# Easiest way to get users current location/

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

What is the fastest/easiest way to get the users location with the CoreLocation framework? Is there a single method that can do this? Or will I have to go thru the whole startUpdatingLocation business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the classic "[Where am I](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application)" example would be most helpful to you.